# Workaround scrollview zoom for android #appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Hi I am building a magazine viewer and I need to zoom and drag the content pages. I am using scrollview but I guess the zoom works only for ios. Is there any workaround for this? I am using `Titanium 5 sdk`, and don't found modules that support it.

Comment: It looks like you've found something that works differently across platforms where it might not need to. Please check if this is a known request at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

On Android you might be able to use http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-enableZoomControls